# Using MockRestServiceServer only in subset of tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, mockrestserviceserver

I want to test outgoing HTTP calls from my service using `MockRestServiceServer`. I got it working using following code:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CommentFetcherTest {

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
CommentFetcher commentFetcher;


@Test
public void shouldCallExternalService(){

    MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

    mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo("/test/endpoint")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET));

    //when
    commentFetcher.fetchData();

    mockServer.verify();

}
}
```

However the problem I run into is that RestTemplate is a bean shared between all tests from suite what makes impossible to further run integration tests which should be calling external services. This results in :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No further requests expected
```

How is it possible to use `MockRestServiceServer` only for subset of tests?
I can't get rid of Dependency Injection through `@Autowired` and construct my service in tests such as

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
CommentFetcher commentFetcher = new CommentFetcher(restTemplate);
```

As this would not read properties from `application.properties` necessary to proper functioning of my service.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the big picture here, but will it be possible for you to autowire `TestRestTemplate` in your integration test classes? BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot provides a convenient way to test your client classes that make use of Spring's `RestTemplate` using `@RestClientTest`.

With this annotation, you get a Spring Test Context that only contains relevant beans and not your whole application context (which is what you currently get with `@SpringBootTest`).

The `MockRestServiceServer` is also part of this context and the `RestTemplate` is configured to target it.

A basic test setup can look like the following:

```
@RestClientTest(CommentFetcher.class)
class UserClientTest {
 
  @Autowired
  private CommentFetcher userClient;
 
  @Autowired
  private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;
 
  // ...
 
 
}
```

What's left is to stub the HTTP method call and then invoke the method on your class under test (`commentFetcher.fetchData();` in your case).

Refer to this [article](https://rieckpil.de/testing-your-spring-resttemplate-with-restclienttest/) if you want to understand more about how `@RestClientTest` can be used to test your `RestTemplate` usage.